# Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

How can I solve this problem on Android Studio when I got this error?

```
Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25
```

[image]

Comment: Click on Install missing platrorm(s) and sync project.

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted the version 26 from my sdk platforms folder ( `C:\Users\[MY USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms` , i.e. `android-26` ) . 
I've then closed android studio and when opening it , i've right-clicked it and opened it with 'Run as Administrator' .

this fixed the issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> SDK Manager on Android Studio. Tick the missing SDK and click apply. It will download and install the required SDK. That solved my issue.